# Not able to create session using devTools when switching from parent window to child window inselenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parent-child, selenium-grid, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am facing below issue only when I use Remote webdriver , working fine locally.

```
    DevTools devtools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
    devtools.createSession();
```

Seeing below exception at createSession line ,

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: Output closed
Build info: version: '4.17.0', revision: 'e52b1be057*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Note: same code is working for parent window(not seeing any exception when trying to create session), but seeing issue once switching from parent to child window and trying to create session.